# How do you keep a flexible rubber coupling from popping off?

Tags: pipe, pvc, pump

I have an effluent tank with a 2" pipe to the leach field about 200 feet away, and a 2" sewage pump.  I went with a 2" rubber coupling and 2" PVC and check valve mainly to allow maximum throughput.  After a few years, the rubber coupling popped free right at the pipe to the leach field which is a horizontal connection.  I assume over time the pressure just slowly pushed it off.  I was afraid of this and made sure to tighten it as much as possible, but it still happened.

What can I do to prevent this from happening again?

[image]

Comment: Maybe check for blockages/clogs causing the pressure to build up.  If the pipes have smooth ends, maybe try pipes with a ridge/barb end so the clamps have something to grab onto.

Comment: use a longer coupling so you can have 2 clamps on each side

Comment: all good answers, hard to pick just 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a 2"  PVC barbed coupling.  The barbs prevent the rubber coupling from slipping off the PVC pipe.  These are commonly used with supply lines that are under pressure.

Something like this:
[image]

Picture is from Parts Warehouse.

That said, I have a similar arrangement to OP's - plain 'ol pvc pipe - for my sump pump discharge pipe, and I don't think the rubber coupling has ever popped off.

Comment: I did order these, for now I just reattached the old coupling is until it's not the cold rainy season.  It should last until then.

Answer (score 3):

The fitting you have should work, if the pipes are properly secured. The fact that it's not working suggests that they are free to move somewhat. Pressure alone won't pop that off, but motion will work it loose. Secure the pipes so they can't move and the problem should stop being a problem.

You could also add two more hose clamps (put the tightening mechanism on the opposite side of the coupling from the two already on there) if you have the pipes fully seated in the coupling.

Comment: IDK how much luck you'd have trying [to keep 200' of pipe from expanding and contracting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/285199/23295). Thanks for the thought though ;)

Comment: Buried in dirt below frost line as it should be, there's very little temperature variation, so very little expansion and contraction.

Comment: I don't really have anything to secure the pump/pipes to.  Though I like the more clamps idea.

Answer (score 2):

Expansion Joint

[image]

Never had a Fernco fail. Don't do many runs at 200' though.

https://www.fernco.com/products/flexible-couplings

Comment: The ones that are *slightly bulbous*.